# TortoiseHg - infinite cloning of repository

Tags: mercurial

I've encountered a quite troubling problem. I've tried to clone repository from the server and I was able to start cloning, but it never ends, and no files are being downloaded on my hard drive. I'm using pagaent with my private key. I've tried it on 3 different PC, and it didn't helped, but I know it is working because some people were able to clone this repository.

Comment: You've tagged your question [tag:git], but your title says "TortoiseHg". Is this a Mercurial or a Git question?

Comment: Right, mistake, it is mercurial

Comment: Try cloning to a low revision without updating, and see if it still takes a long time: `hg clone --noupdate -r 100 <SRC> <DST>`. Then, you can pull the rest progressively.

Comment: Well it was after all a problem from server side, but thanks everyone for help!